# UIActivity View Conntroller : Custom Activity Placement

Tags: ios, customization, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop

When I use **UIActivityViewController** can I place a custom Activity on the **top** of the default activities. That is at the place where AirDrop appears. Please clarify this. Let me know if there is some other method to do this.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, unfortunately not possible. You are only able to add an activity to the other two sections.